# Why doesn't retagging get any reputation?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation

I read [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Great [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) and [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238)

Because;

[image]

**Users gain reputation when:**

- Your Question is voted *Helpful*: +5
- Your Answer is voted *Helpful*: +10
- Your Answer is marked *Accepted*: +15
- You marked an answer to your question as *Accepted*: +2
- A down vote on your Question or Answer is removed: +2
- You possess less than 2000 reputation, and an [edit you have submitted is accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77505/edit-a-question-from-other-user-and-get-2-rep): +2
- You remove your down vote from a Question or Answer you have voted as *Not Helpful*: +1
- The bounty on a question is awarded to your answer: **+full bounty amount**
- The bounty time for a question expires and your answer had the highest votes (the bounty is divided equally if there's a tie): **+1/2 of the bounty amount**

The question is, why doesn't retagging gain you any reputation? Isn't it helpful to someone in finding the question?

Improving formatting results in +2 reputation, for example. I think retagging should get at least 2 reputation points.

What do you think about this?

Comment: +1 I believe you are a good editor :-)

Comment: I thought retag option was gone once anyone can suggest full edit?

Comment: > "But retag is not. Isn't that strange?", Well, I think its because they don't take retagging as an "Edit" to the post according to current logic, IIRC. I think it should be improvable but not sure how they will think.

Comment: You get a badge. I don't think a user deserves rep for *every* tag edit they make. You've got to contribute some good content once in a while, too!

Comment: No lie, got a fortune last night that came instantly true.  "You are about to come into a fortune."  And I had.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can get +2 for a retag if it goes through the suggested edits.  See this question: [Retagging through suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78277/retagging-through-suggested-edits)

Users with 2,000+ rep, edit or retag but get no reputation for either.  The difference is that no one has to review/accept the 2,000+ users edits.

Comment: +1 and I confirm, I got some +2 for retag until I reach 500 and got the retag questions Privileges.

Comment: So if i have 2000+ rep, I get +2 rep for retag or suggested edit. But that's not fare. For example; I have edit right now but doesn't matter i have +2000 or -2000 rep, in either case this is an 'EDIT'. It should get +2 rep.

Comment: @Soner No, it's fair: First it's put a ceiling on the rep you could get form those action. Second, once you reach the rep to get those Privileges, you somewhat proved that you understand the mechanism of the site and you shouldn't need a cookie every time you do it right.

Comment: No, you get the +2 rep because two other users did agree with your edit.

Comment: @Mete.DavRob Yes you are right but i just want to say... Any way. You are right! That doesn't good for SO mechanism.

Comment: Cookiebook. lol

Answer (score 5):

Reputation in general is given to you by other people for something you do. Badges are given for what you do. Retagging is something you do.

Comment: But if you don't nothing, you have no rep.. Isn't relevant..

Comment: Reputation in general is given to you by other people for **something you do**

Comment: Yes of course. I've edited my answer to include that.