# Delete a suggested edit that I don't want to happen

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, cancel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retagging through suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78277/retagging-through-suggested-edits)

I suggested an edit to a post and ended up only editing the tags.  I realized after I did this that I had the rep to edit the tags and could have just done that.  I can't figure out how to delete the suggested edit I had created that hasn't been approved yet.

Is there a way?  If not, let's make one, even editors make mistakes.

Comment: @jon, that is a similar circumstance, but I specifically want to be able to take back edits I've made before they're committed.